# django-allauth callback url for github?

Tags: github, oauth, django-allauth

The [django-allauth readme](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) contains specific info on how to set up authentication using several providers, but not Github.

I would assume based on the general pattern given that the correct callback url for github is

`http://example.com/accounts/github/login/callback/`

However, github won't let me sign up at https://github.com/settings/applications using that callback, and says "Callback URL is invalid.

What's the correct URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind. The above is the correct callback url. I was confused thinking that the validation error on github's form was updating live. Turns out the error was old; I just had to click submit on the form again!